# Passing variable between functions - php

Tags: php, function, variables

Below is an edited version of my actual code:

```
<?php

include ('login_info.php');

class modernCMS {

var $host;
var $username;
var $password;
var $db;
var $url;


function connect(){
    $con = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
    mysql_select_db($this->db, $con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_set_charset('utf8');

}


function get_coordinates(){

$sql ="select lat, lng from postcodes LIMIT 1;";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lng = $row['lng'];

    }
}


 function get_name(){

 $sql ="select name from places WHERE lat=$lat AND lng=$lng LIMIT 1;";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $name = $row['name'];

echo $name;


     }
}


?>
```

Then within a separate document i have an include for the file above. I call the function get name using the following:

```
<?=$obj->get_name()?>
```

get_name actually contains a calculation for calculating the distance between two points however because its a lengthy calculation i have left it out of the example above.

Its important that i can just use $obj->get_name() to get the output for $lat and $lng

Comment: you can pass them as parameters

Comment: If you need a getter and setter, make a Coordinate object. PHP is an OOP language :-)

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). However, using things like arguments, returns, arrays, objects, and properties are all *MUCH* preferable to using global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a scoping issue. The variables are only available to the function that declared them. To make them available, you can either pass the variables to the function explicitly (you need to make sure you always call `get_coordinates()` before `display_coordinates()` though, otherwise you'll have undefined values), or using global variables (bad idea).

The best method is probably to make a class for it (although it depends on how you intend to use it). Your variables will always be in scope, and you won't run the risk of trying to run the `display_coordinates()` function before you've initialized the variables.

```
class Coordinate
{
    // These are the variables where the coords will be stored.
    // They are available to everything within the {}'s after 
    // "class Coordinate"  and can be accessed with
    // $this->_<varname>.
    protected $_lat;
    protected $_long;

    // This is a special function automatically called when 
    // you call "new Coordinate"
    public function __construct($lat, $long)
    {
        // Here, whatever was passed into "new Coordinate" is
        // now stored in our variables above.
        $this->_lat  = $lat;
        $this->_long = $long;
    }

    // This takes the values are stored in our variables,
    // and simply displays them.
    public function display()
    {
        echo $this->_lat;
        echo $this->_long;
    }
}

// This creates a new Coordinate "object". 25 and 5 have been stored inside.
$coordinate = new Coordinate(25, 5); // 25 and 5 are now stored in $coordinate.
$coordinate->display(); // Since $coordinate already "knows" about 25 and 5
                        // it can display them.

// It's important to note, that each time you run "new Coordinate",
// you're creating an new "object" that isn't linked to the other objects.
$coord2 = new Coordinate(99, 1);
$coord2->display(); // This will print 99 and 1, not 25 and 5.

// $coordinate is still around though, and still knows about 25 and 5.
$coordinate->display(); // Will still print 25 and 5.
```

You should read up on [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) to understand more about this.

To put this together with your original code, you would do something like this,

```
function get_coordinates()
{
     return new Coordinate(25, 5);
}

function display_coordinates($coord)
{
    $coord->display();
}

$c = get_coordinates();
display_coordinates($c);
// or just "display_coordinates(get_coordinates());"
```

## Edit after question updated

There are a few bad practices in your code, but here's some quick steps to get what you want.

```
// Copy the Coordinate class from my answer above, but add two new
// lines before the final "}"
public function getLatitude()  { return $this->_lat; }
public function getLongitude() { return $this->_long; }

// Put the Coordinate class definition before this line
class modernCMS {

/////

// In your code, after this line near the top
var $url;

// Add this
var $coord;

/////

// In your get_coordinates(), change this...
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lng = $row['lng'];

// To this...
$this->coord = new Coordinate($lat, $lng);

/////

// In your get_name(), add two lines to the start of your function.
function get_name(){
    $lat = $this->coord->getLatitude();
    $lng = $this->coord->getLongitude();
```

*Unrelated to your question, but you should also read about "SQL Injection" as query in `get_name()` is vulnerable. Not a big deal here, since the data comes from your other query anyway, but still good practice not to use parameters directly in a query string.*

Comment: This example confuses me because you seem to be setting the values outside of both functions. Its important that the values are set in the first function are they are coming from an sql statement.

Comment: I will add some comments to the code to try and make it clearer to understand.

Comment: I've added comments to hopefully explain what is happening better. There is only so much that can be explained in such a short answer though. Reading the two documents I've referenced at the end is going to be the best way to get a full understanding of what is going on. Don't be put off by the length of the docs, this isn't something that's easy to grasp at first, but both scoping and classes/objects are an important topic to learn.

Comment: Last question: Can i set : $coordinate = new Coordinate(25, 5); within a separate function?

Comment: Yes, but `$coordinate` will only be available in that separate function. You wouldn't be able to call `$coordinate->display();` from a separate function unless you make `$coordinate` global, or pass it into the second function.

Comment: @andrewanderson You can load the coordinates in another function, call `new Coordinate(...)` and *return* the new coordinate object.  It can then be passed to any other function.  No need for globals. (Rich, perhaps you could update your answer to show how you might do that -- it's already a good answer, or I'd add it to mine).

Comment: I have edited my original question as i don't believe i explained it properly first time around. I hope it makes more sense now and you can see why i am confused about setting the values outside the first function. and displaying them outside the second function. My code is very short so i am really not concerned if i have to use Global variables. Just really looking for a solution that's works.

Comment: @andrewanderson I've added an update based on the changes to your question. Some quick steps to get you what you want. I highly encourage you to read the docs that have been linked though, so that you at least understand what's going on.

Comment: I could be wrong... but i thought PHP didnt allow you to have a class within a class? I already have class modernCMS which contains the current functions. I have a separate php file which cleanses the users input to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Correct, you can't have a class within a class, you can define two classes in the same file though (not great practice, but can be done). You need to put the Coordinate class before the modernCMS class in your file.

Answer (score 4):

Functions operate within function scope, so the variables that you've set in `get_coordinates()` are local variables.  To create global variables, you can use the global keyword:

```
<?php

function get_coordinates()
{
global $lat, $lng;
$lat = 25;
$lng = 5;
}

function display_coordinates()
{
global $lat, $lng;
echo $lat;
echo $lng;
}

get_coordinates();
display_coordinates();
```

Or `$GLOBALS` array:

```
<?php

function get_coordinates()
{
$GLOBALS['lat'] = 25;
$GLOBALS['lng'] = 5;
}

function display_coordinates()
{
echo $GLOBALS['lat'];
echo $GLOBALS['lng'];
}

get_coordinates();
display_coordinates();
```

However, this may not be the best way to set/access these variables because any function can change their state at any time, and you must call one function to set them before calling the other to display them.  If you can describe your specific goal, you might be able to get better advice.

One **better** way to accomplish this is to use a class, and pass the object where you need it (this simple example does not demonstrate proper [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), but is a good starting point):

```
<?php

class Coordinates {
  public $lat;
  public $lng;

  public function __construct($lat, $lng) {
    $this->lat = $lat;
    $this->lng = $lng;
  } 

  public function display_coordinates() {
    echo $this->lat . "\n";
    echo $this->lng . "\n";
  }
}

function get_coordinates() {
  return new Coordinates(25, 5);
}

$coords = get_coordinates();
$coords->display_coordinates();


function output_coordinates($coordinates) {
  $coordinates->display_coordinates();
}
output_coordinates($coords);
```

Another way that is commonly used in PHP is to pass things in associative arrays (arrays with strings for indexes).  I don't prefer this usually, because the array does not declare what it intends to hold, but it is an option:

```
<?php

function get_coordinates() {
  return array('lat' => 25, 'lng' => 5);
}

function output_coordinates($coordinates) {
  echo $coordinates['lat'] . '\n';
  echo $coordinates['lng'] . '\n';
}

$coords = get_coordinates();
output_coordinates($coords);
```

Comment: are classes and objects automatically *better* ?

Comment: @Dagon No? I didn't mean to imply that, either.  But it helps with dependencies, encapsulation and responsibility because you group similar properties and methods together, eliminating the burden of remembering what is in global space (and at what point).  This code isn't much longer or more complicated, and yet more organized and easier to extend.

Comment: its the screaming bold that got me, but no bun fight intended ;-)

Comment: Both Examples above using global or $GLOBALS didn't work for me. I am not sure if i am missing something really simple here.

Comment: @Dagon I just wanted to actually be helpful and point to one better way to do things.

Comment: @andrewanderson I realized in the first example (`global`) that I forgot to declare the globals in the second function.  I have updated both to include full code that works for me.  What version of PHP are you using?  Are you modifying the code at all?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

```
function get_coordinates(&$lat, &$lng)
{
     $lat = 25;
     $lng = 5;
}

function display_coordinates($lat, $lng)
{
     echo $lat;
     echo $lng;
}

$lat = 0;
$lng = 0;

// assign values to variables
get_coordinates( $lat, $lng );

// use function to display them...
display_coordinates ($lat, $lng);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about Session?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

## Creating New Session

```
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
```

## Getting Session

```
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/

$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*session created*/

echo $_SESSION["newsession"];
/*session was getting*/
```

## Updating Session

```
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/

$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*it is my new session*/

$_SESSION["newsession"]=$updatedvalue;
/*session updated*/
```

## Deleting Session

```
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/

$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;

unset($_SESSION["newsession"]);
/*session deleted. if you try using this you've got an error*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Coordinate.class.php` file:

```php
<?php
class Coordinate {
  var $latitude;
  var $longitude;

  public function getLatitude() {
    return $this->latitude;
  }

  protected function setLatitude($latitude) {
    $this->latitude = floatval($latitude);
  }

  public function getLongitude() {
    return $this->longitude;
  }

  protected function setLongitude($longitude) {
    $this->longitude = floatval($longitude);
  }

  public function __construct() {
    // Overload
    if (func_num_args() == 2) {
      $this->setLatitude(func_get_arg(0));
      $this->setLongitude(func_get_arg(1));
    }
    // Default
    else {
      $this->setLatitude(0);
      $this->setLongitude(0);
    }
  }

  public function displayCoordinate() {
    printf("Latitude: %.2f, Longitude: %.2f\n",
      $this->getLatitude(),
      $this->getLongitude());
  }
}

function main() {
  $c = new Coordinate (25, 5);
  $c->displayCoordinate();
}

main();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change of another post.. I think the better way:

```
function get_coordinates()
{
    return array(
        "lat" => 25,
        "lng" => 5
    );

}

function display_coordinates($latLongArray)
{
     echo $latLongArray['lat'];
     echo $latLongArray['lng'];
}


// assign values to variables
$latLongArray = get_coordinates();

// use function to display them...
display_coordinates ($latLongArray);
```