# Laravel Controller use same object in two functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to use a object variable instantiated from a class in two functions?

Here's the code I've tried, but its just returning `null`:

```
class bookAppointmentsController extends APIController
{
    private $business;  

    public funcition check($key)
    {
        $this->business = new APIClass();
        $setconnection = $this->business->connectAPI($key);
    }

    public function book()
    {
        dd($this->business) //returns null
        $this->business->book();
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the `$business` object in two functions but it does not work, when I `dd($business)` it returns null

Any way to do this?

Comment: this is suppose to be normal. Best practices insist on controller being stateless, thus a call should not depend from a precedent call.
Although you can make it, and your code does not work for this. With each request you re-bootstrap your application, meaning when calling the book action, the check action never occured before. You would have to store your object in a file / database / session or anything else that wouldn't be reset by a new call.

Comment: Any way to use this object in two functions? I am stuck .

Comment: This is a scooping issue this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016830/5203821

Comment: Are you calling the two functions during the same request? Otherwise, as @Unex commented, you need some way to persist `$business` between requests.

Comment: No, the requests are separate that's why I needed two functions. I just need to carry over the confirmation code from `check` to `book` but it's proving really hard to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the instantiation to the constructor:

```
public function __construct(APIClass $business)
{
    $this->business = $business;
}
```

However, it would be better if you make Laravel do the heavy lifting and prepare the `APIClass` for you.

In your `AppServicePorvider` under the register method, you can create the `APIClass`

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('APIClass', function ($app) {
        $api = new APIClass();
        // Do any logic required to prepare and check the api
        $key = config('API_KEY');
        $api->connectAPI($key);
        return $api;
    });

}
```

Check the [documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding) for more details.

Comment: Actually, it's not working. The second function does not carry the same object instance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution could be to make the variable **Global**

You could make the variable global:

```
function method( $args ) {
    global $newVar;
    $newVar = "Something";

}

function second_method() {
    global $newVar;
    echo $newVar;
}
```

Or you could return it from the first method and use it in the second method

```
public function check($key)
{
    $this->business = new APIClass();
    $setconnection = $this->business->connectAPI($key);
    return $this->business;
}

public function book()
{
   $business = check($key);
   $business->book();
}
```